# Real time messaging on website

Tags: http, real-time, message

Can a client start a connection with another client through the internet for instant messaging by website? Or can a server start a request to a client to update the website?

Comment: Your question needs more information and context. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some general guidance.

Comment: Real Time is not exaclty what you are looking for, search for  Websockets instead....

Comment: well, it is still in planning, so I just want to find better way to do it

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ thanks for advise, I will check on it